# show popup when we click marquee in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using marquee for displaying news and announcement. Can anybody tell me how can we show the popup. When we click the marquee in asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jquery ui. For Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually i want to show the news details in popup window based on marquee news. Is there any code related to asp or html?

Comment: For displaying pop up you have two options - 1. AJAX Modal Pop up  2. Jquery or other Javascript based pop up. You need to write the code in ASP that on click of news, pop up shows up. Please visit http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx for more info on AJAX pop up.

Comment: Thank you for your nice response. This is what i want. Once again thanks,